# Why are upvotes and downvotes locked after 5 minutes?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

5 minutes after voting a lock is placed on votes for the question/answer. A user can only recast his/her vote if the post is edited.

So my question is

1. Why is there a locking mechanism on question/answers?
2. Should the locking time be increased to 10 min OR 15 min?

Comment: You can change your vote once the post is edited.

Comment: @JoshMein Yes i know , I have included this in my question..:)

Comment: Then what is the problem? Why would you change your vote if nothing has changed in the post. It seems like you need to be more thorough in your decision before voting.

Comment: Well, in my case it was because I missed a defect in the answer that was revealed to me by a subsequent comment. I understand wanting to protect upvotes against removal when the environment changes and the answer is no longer relevant, but the 5 minute limit seems extreme, particular when there's a lot of comment activity during the first few hours.